# Scrapy Spider not extracting xpath data

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to python. I usually use php to crawl data. I'm trying to switch to python. I'm following the tutorial from here.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

I'm looking to crawl countries and capitals from this wikipedia page.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_in_alphabetical_order

My spider program is:

```
import scrapy

class CountrySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "countryCapitals"
    allowed_domains = ["wikipedia.org"]
    start_urls = [
                    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_in_alphabetical_order"
                    ]

    def parse(self, response):
            for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]/tbody/tr'):
                    country = sel.xpath('//td[1]').extract()
                    capital = sel.xpath('td[2]/b/span.text()').extract()
                    print country , capital
```

It is not printing any data as it was supposed to. Any help in this is appreciated.

Comment: first print value returned by `xpath` - maybe it is `None` or empty list

Comment: It is not empty as I checked it in chrome developer tools. But it is not printing it here. It is just "print sel" here right?

Comment: `print response.xpath( ... )`. "chrome developer tools" is not python. It can show you data created by javascript. And it show data parsed into tree object - not HTML source code. For example chrome shows `tbody` even if there is no `tbody` in source file.

Comment: `tbody` in your `xpath` can be the problem.

Comment: You should try to use for debug a technique from Scrapy manual: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html

Comment: @furas That is the problem. the tbody tag seems to be not there in the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the HTML shown in the browser console is a bit different than the original source code. For instance, like @furas pointed out, the `tdoby` tag is part of the problem. But also the xpath to extract the capital text is incorrect.

I made a test with the parse method below and it worked fine to me, I change the country xpath also in order to extract the country text.

```
def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]/tr'):
                country = sel.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract()
                capital = sel.xpath('td[2]//a/text()').extract()
                print country , capital
```

Partial output example:

```
[u'Abu Dhabi'] [u'United Arab Emirates']
[u'Abuja'] [u'Nigeria']
[u'Accra'] [u'Ghana']
[u'Adamstown'] [u'Pitcairn Islands']
[u'Addis Ababa'] [u'Ethiopia']
[u'Algiers'] [u'Algeria']
[u'Alofi'] [u'Niue']
[u'Amman'] [u'Jordan']
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code. I think the problem is with your xpath. I am assuming that you are using chrome functionality to copy the xpath.
I am not good with xpath myself. I tried to use .css() method to print the values out. I used:

```
print response.css('div.mw-content-ltr > table').extract()
```

It works fine. To get the second table just put the class or id of that table in the above line. I believe it should work fine.